# How to get filtered list size in Thymeleaf when combining th:each and th:if?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to get the list size of a looped th:each after i use th:if to filter out some data, but it is giving me the full list size instead of the filtered list size

Assuming transaction list size is 5, and it contains 3 of the type I am trying to filter, it still returns the list size as 5 instead of 3. If i print out the values, only 3 appears so I know the data is fine and thymeleaf can filter it as expected

```
<th:block th:each="transaction,iter : ${transactions}" th:object="${transaction}" th:if="${transaction.test} == 'test'">
<tr>
<td><span th:text="${iter.size}"></span></td>
</tr>
</th:block>
```

I expect the output to be 3 because the transaction list it contains 3 'test' values, and 2 junk values. However it is giving me a size of 5 instead of 3. Printing out the values, it generates 3 rows (as expected), but with a value of 5 (should be 3 after being filtered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:if` doesn't change the list.  It just controls whether or not a piece of HTML shows up.

That being said, you can accomplish this with [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection).  For example, something like this:

```
<tr th:with="filtered=${transactions.?[test == 'Test']}">
    <td th:text="${filtered.size()}" />
</tr>
```